# Unable to enable php5.6-gd in apache2 under a debian 10

Tags: php, apache, debian

### Our system

I have this s.o.

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster

# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Actual version of apache

> No, we cannot upgrade it

```
# apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Server built:   2019-10-13T15:43:54
```

This is our php

> Yes php 5.6 is old and deprecated. We **cannot** upgrade this old legacy app

```
# php -v
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.40-0+deb8u12 (cli) (built: Jun 28 2020 09:37:30)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

### The problem

As you can see above

> Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so:

But it's installed, and, both for cli and for apache2, `the mods-avaiable\gd.ini` has been simlinked in the respective `conf.d`.

```
# apt-get install php5.6-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5.6-gd is already the newest version (5.6.40-52+0~20210701.54+debian10~1.gbpc0026e).
```

In spite of this, PHP is right, there is no `/usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so` file.

But there is a gd.so in a generic `php` folder

```
find / -name "gd.so"
/usr/lib/php/20131226/gd.so
```

### Question

what is the right way to enable php5.6-gd ?

Comment: Did you symlink the gd.so in the conf.d directories or was it done automatically?

Comment: I didn't symlink the gd.so.  I manually created a symlink to gd.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I did this to resolve, but i expect a better solution if available

```
cp /usr/lib/php/20131226/gd.so /usr/lib/php5/20131226/gd.so

cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
ln -s ../../mods-available/gd.ini 20-gd.ini

cd /etc/php5/apache/conf.d
ln -s ../../mods-available/gd.ini 20-gd.ini

systemctl restart apache2
```

It works

I still do not understand why some extensions are under `/usr/lib/php5` and this one is found under `/usr/lib/php`.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion. Somehow, the gd.so that you got written in is wrong. In my Ubuntu, there's no /usr/lib/php5 folder but /usr/lib/php. 

I guess there's an issue in the generation of the .ini files.

Comment: in the .ini file there is no path, only `extension=gd.so` but probably in the past this server could have been manually tricked from some programmers